# Rake aborts in Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I had create a empty new rails project with a scaffold successfully but when I try `rake db:create`, it throws me an error: `rake aborted! uninitialized constant Rake::DSL`.

As other SO post mentioned, I tried setting my Gemfile to gem 'rake', '0.8.7', but rake gives me another error:

> You have requested:   rake = 0.8.7
>
> The bundle currently has rake locked at 0.9.2.2. Try running `bundle
>   update rake` Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Then I did as the message said and update rake and bundle install. Same error.

It is nice and easy experience to develop a project a rails but it is a nightmare porting between ruby versions, rails versions, difference gem and plugin versions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete your Gemfile.lock, and type this on your terminal:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

> I had create a empty new rails project with a scaffold successfully but when I try rake db:create, it throws me an error: rake aborted! uninitialized constant Rake::DSL.

for this problem I'd suggest running all rake tasks via `bundle exec rake ...`